# How to drop the contents of the block cache of a partition/drive in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, disk, cache

(Moved from Stack Overflow.)

I have a simple backup process that copies a bunch of files to a USB flash drive. I want to verify that copying was successful by re-reading the flash drive and comparing that with the original files. I want to ensure that the re-read reads the flash drive and doesn't just return data that Linux has cached. (I expect that the flash drive has internal caches, but I'm not worried about those.) How do I programmatically ensure Linux drops cached information for a particular filesystem (or perhaps, a particular drive partition)? (I could umount the flash drive and physically remove and reinsert it, but I would prefer a programmatic solution.)

I am currently umounting and then mounting the filesystem, which I expect causes Linux to drop cached data which is organized "by file". But there might be a lower-level block cache that is organized "by partition" or "by device" that is not affected by that.

I know of `echo N >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, but that drops cached blocks for all filesystems, which is broader than I need and may cause performance degradation for other filesystems.

There is a blockdev command that would be the natural place for this functionality, but it has no option for dropping a cache (as of Linux 5.17.12). (It does have `--flushbufs`, but that isn't what I need.)

Comment: Could you write a simple C wrapper around a `syncfs` system call? `man 2 syncfs`

Comment: @waltinator the goal here isn’t to ensure that everything is written to disk, it’s to ensure that no data from the relevant file system remains in cache so that the verification is forced to actually read from the underlying device.

Comment: I haven't been able to find the code in the Linux kernel that implements drop_caches.  The header for it is ```int drop_caches_sysctl_handler(struct ctl_table *, int, void *, size_t *, loff_t *);``` in ```include/linux/mm.h``` but I haven't found the corresponding .c.

Comment: ```https://codebrowser.dev/linux/linux/fs/drop_caches.c.html``` shows that writing bit 1 to ```drop_caches``` is implemented by ```iterate_supers(drop_pagecache_sb, NULL)```, which shows that the actual dropping is done on a per-superblock basis.  This suggests an IOCTL could be written that calls ```drop_pagecache_sb``` for only one superblock, in somewhat the same way that ```blockdev --flushbufs``` calls the  ioctl BLKFLSBUF.  But someone who understands the Linux disk system needs to check if there are complexities that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution, but less than ideal:  It turns out that due to the previous version of my backup process, it is producing an ISO 9660 file of the file tree that I am backing up.  I could copy the ISO to the backup medium using `dd oflag=direct` so that the blocks aren't put into the cache.  Then to verify the backup, I could use `cmp`, which has to read the blocks from the medium.  The individual files in the tree can be accessed by mounting the ISO file somewhere.

Because the writes bypass the cache, they might not get advantage of clever algorithms in the kernel to batch writes to reduce "wear" on the drive. It seems like that can be avoided by transferring in blocks that contain whole write pages.  It looks like write pages for flash drives are usually 64kiB or less, so `dd bs=128K` should suffice for a few years.

And `dd` seems to copy trailing partial blocks correctly.

`cp` doesn't seem to have a direct-write option.